# NSDateFormatter behavior problem

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I have a problem using NSDateFormatter in iPhone programming.
Below is my code snippet.

```
NSString *inputDate = @"2011-03-14";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *entryDate = [formatter dateFromString:inputDate];
[formatter release]
```

The result I am getting is

> 2011-03-13 16:00:00 +0000

which is the GMT equivalent of 2011-03-14 00:00:00. (My time zone is GMT +08:00)

Why I am getting this? How to get 2011-03-14 00:00:00 as the result?

Thanks.

~Jan

Answer (score 2):

You can set the timezone using

```
[formatter setTimeZone:...]
```

. Alternatively I would try to just set the formatter's locale by

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"..."];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried both, but the result was similar. Furthermore my formatter's timezone and locale are correctly set to the local settings by default.

Answer (score 0):

Pls take a look at this

[NSDateFormatter returns unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598574/nsdateformatter-returns-unexpected-results)

This is what [Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598574/nsdateformatter-returns-unexpected-results) recommends

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, setting the time zone of the formatters does not seem to fix the problem. I have tried that, but the answer was the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the timezone to your original string

```
NSString *inputDate = @"2011-03-14+0800";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddZZZ"];
NSDate *entryDate = [formatter dateFromString:inputDate];
[formatter release]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But unfortunately this didn't work :(